The position of my game projectile is being reseted in my class every update
I created a small game:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include "raylib.h"
#include "raymath.h"

using namespace std;

// Constant Values
const int cell_size = 20; // Should be equal to the pixel size of images
const int cell_count = 40;
const int game_height = cell_size * cell_count, game_width = cell_size * cell_count;
const int FPS = 60;
const int font_size = 40;
const int game_offset = 100;

// Colors
map<string, Color> color = {
    {"white", {255, 255, 255, 255}},
    {"black", {0, 0, 0, 255}      },
    {"red"  , {255, 0, 0, 255}    },
    {"green", {0, 255, 0, 255}    },
    {"blue" , {0, 0, 255, 255}    }
 };

// Classes
class Cannon {
public:
    float cannon_height = cell_size * 6;
    float cannon_width = cell_size * 4;
    int speed = 2;
    float reload_time = 2; // Seconds

    vector<Vector2> position = {
        {game_width / 2, game_height - cannon_height},
        {game_width / 2 - cannon_width / 2, game_height},
        {game_width / 2 + cannon_width / 2, game_height}
    }; // Top, Bottom Left, Bottom, Right

    void Update() {
        Move();
    }

    void Draw() {
        DrawTriangle(position[0], position[1], position[2], RED);
    }

    void Move() {
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT) && position[2].x <= game_width - speed) {
            for (int i = 0; i < position.size(); i++)
                position[i].x += speed;
        }
        if (IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT) && position[1].x >= speed) {
            for (int i = 0; i < position.size(); i++)
                position[i].x -= speed;
        }
    }
};

class Bomb {
public:
    Vector2 position;
    float radius = 10;
    int speed = 200;

    Bomb(Vector2 pos) {
        position = pos;
    }

    void Update() {
        Move();
    }

    void Draw() {
        DrawCircle(position.x, position.y - radius, radius, RED);
    }

    void Move() {
        position.y -= speed;
    }
};

class Game {
public:
    Cannon cannon = Cannon();
    deque<Bomb> bombs;

    double last_update_time = 0;
    
    void Draw() {
        cannon.Draw();
        for (Bomb bomb : bombs) {
            bomb.Draw();
        }
    }

    void DisplayText() {

    }

    void Update() {
        if (bombs.size() > 0)
            cout << bombs[0].position.y << endl;
        Shoot();
        cannon.Update();
        for (Bomb bomb : bombs)
            bomb.Update();
        if (bombs.size() > 0)
            cout << bombs[0].position.y << endl;
    }

    void Shoot() {
        if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE) && Time(cannon.reload_time))
            bombs.push_front(Bomb(cannon.position[0]));
    }

    void GameOver() {

    }

    bool Time(double time_interval) {
        double current_time = GetTime();
        
        if (current_time - last_update_time >= time_interval) {
            last_update_time = current_time;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Create Window
    InitWindow(game_width, game_height, "Ernest");
    SetTargetFPS(FPS);

    // Main Class
    Game game = Game();

    // Main Loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();

        // Update Elements
        game.Update();

        // Draw Elements
        ClearBackground(color["black"]);
        game.Draw();

        EndDrawing();
    }

    // Close Window
    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}

...but i ran into an issue:
The position of my projectile (bomb) should change, but it keeps getting reseted to its original value everytime.

Can't tell if that's the only problem, but for(Bomb bomb : bombs) creates copy of each element in bombs, so your Update() only happens to the copy. You have to iterate over references instead: for(Bomb& bomb : bombs)

Almost always when we get these kind of 'reset' questions the reason is that what is being changed is a copy of the thing that the OP wants to be changed. Beginners often have an 'everything is a reference' misunderstanding. In C++ that's not true, if you want a reference you have to ask for one.
